# Angular: How to have two different index.html files depending on the route

Tags: javascript, html, angular, localization, cdn

I have been working on a Angular application that unfortunately requires me to have two different index.html files due each needing to use different scripts. I originally attempted to dynamically inject the JavaScript however this wont work and proved troublesome.

Is it possible to have depending on the route change the index file loaded?

Ie.

http://localhost:4200/index-en.html

http://localhost:4200/index-fr.html

Im aware that it is best practice to use i18n to handle different languages however I must use separate scripts in each html file to generate the page content.